# Azure devops cant open the code coverage file

Tags: azure-devops, code-coverage, azure-pipelines

Hi guys i have a problem with my code coverage of my azure pipeline. When the CI gets trigged for the master branch the agent has a job to test the .net core. When i use this test i have to configure the route and also enable the code coverage. After the CI has been done it ended succesfully and i can download a file with the code coverage. The problem i have is i cant open this file, not with visual studio or anything else. Aynone that knows how i can fix this problem and maby i didnt configure it right?

Picture of my settings: [image]
picture of the file [image]
picture of the error `https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxqdI.png`

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are using the wrong configuration. I'm afraid `--collect"Code coverage"` will not work.

You could add a .NET core test task and add `/p:CollectCoverage=true` argument then use report generate task for adding code coverage reports.

More detail steps, please refer below tutorials:

- [ASP.NET Core code coverage reports on Azure DevOps](https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet-core-azure-devops-code-coverage/)
- [Azure DevOps, unit testing and code coverage with .Net Core](https://anthonyison.com/azure-devops-unit-testing-and-code-coverage-with-net-core/)

Comment: i get the error ##[warning]No test result files matching **/TEST-*.xml were found. when i use the publish test result task

Comment: @JasonD Have you checked the log if the test report `xx.xml` generated properly? If you are using publish test result task , please uncheck "Publish test results and code coverage" in .NET core test task.

Comment: i was sick so i didnt had the chance to try it sorry will do it soon

Comment: what i found is that it works but you need to have a payed version of visual studio to open te file

Comment: Hi @JasonD Thanks for your kindly response. That's an expect  behavior. **The code coverage feature is available only in Visual Studio Enterprise edition.**  You could find related info in our official doc here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/using-code-coverage-to-determine-how-much-code-is-being-tested?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

To generate code coverage please follow this steps

1. Restore nuget packages
   [image]
2. Build the app
   [image]
3. Run unit tests (You need to add nuegte package to test projects -> coverlet.collector to use 'XPlat Code Coverage')
   [image]
4. Install report generator
   [image]
5. Run report generator
   [image]
6. Publish code coverage
   [image]